# Side bumper fix

Tags: toyota, car

I need to fix this side bumper and I was wondering if it was an easy fix like I could do it myself to save money or if I have to I somone to fix it for me?

If I can do it myself what are some ways I can do it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! I see you've tagged this as Toyota but could you tell us the model and year of the car?

Comment: Also provide some better pics for context.